# PHP addslashes to a $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, addslashes

I try put addslashes on a $_POST array. However, google returns me "Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards)."
Any one knows how to fix this?

This is my code
Form

```
echo '<form name="misc_settings" action="?action=misc_settings_submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

foreach($miscsettings as $miscsetting){
    $misc_id = $miscsetting['id'];
    $misc_name = $miscsetting['name'];
    $misc_text = stripslashes($miscsetting['text']);

echo '<input type="hidden" name="misc_id[]" value="' . $misc_id . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="misc_name[]" value="' . $misc_name . '">';
echo '<div class="field_name">' . $misc_name . ': <div class="field_value"><textarea name="misc_text[]">' . $misc_text . '</textarea></div></div>';

}

echo '<div class="submit_field"><input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Clear"></div>';
echo '</form>';
```

submit form

```
$misc_id = $_POST['misc_id'];
$misc_name = $_POST['misc_name'];
#$misc_text = $_POST['misc_text'];
$misc_text = array_map('addslashes', $_POST['misc_text']);

    for($i=0;$i<count($misc_id);$i++)
    {
        if($misc_name[$i]!="" && $misc_text[$i]!="")
        {
            echo $misc_id[$i] . '<br />';
            echo $misc_name[$i] . '<br />';
            echo $misc_text[$i] . '<br /><br />';

            $miscClass->updateMiscSetting($misc_id[$i], $misc_text[$i]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this:

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

before sending any output to the client solved that error in my case